# Advisory lock in Python not accepting bigint?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, locking

for my application I had to implement an transaction advisory_lock using sqlalchemy.

The function to lock on the id is like this:

```
async def acquire_lock(self, _id: int) -> None:
    lock_query = select([func.pg_advisory_xact_lock(_id)])
    await self._connection.execute(lock_query)
```

Now the function locks the transaction for the ID as I want, but I am running into an issue of too large ints being passed to it. I am getitng errors such as `sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.asyncpg.Error) <class 'asyncpg.exceptions.DataError'>: invalid input for query argument $1: 151119767311396900114781881965476902306 (value out of int32 range)`

This is bit confusing as in documentation is that `pg_advisory_xact_lock` should accept a `bigint` just fine. What am I doing wrong here? Should I use some hashing logic here?

Comment: Not sure, but it looks like the problem is your Python code, where you declared it as `int`.

Comment: That value is also out of range for bigint!

Comment: Hmm, yeah. The issue is the `int` value is coming from casted `uuid` value.